# Springboot hibarnate error : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement with database name has bar symbol

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

as title ,my springboot version is 2.1.4，

database name eg：my-db

it was available before upgrading from 1.5V

now i  add one column in model，then it throw this Error when program startup。。。

```
application.yaml set:ddl-auto: update


org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL ”alert table my-db.test add column name varchar(25)“ via JDBC Statement
```

Answer (score 0):

alert table my-db.test add column name varchar(25);

Not sure from where you get this query.
the right syntex for this query is:

alter table  my-db.test add column name varchar(25);

Comment: not the same? it's mysql can't read database name with bar symbol  from  hibernate。

 i want this effect ： alert table \`my-db\`.test add column name varchar(25);